# Dynamically build a class member variable

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependency-injection

I am trying to setup my php (Zend Framework) project through `injection dependence`. So far when I instanciated a model, I would pass the `table` and the `view` (database view) to my model like that:

```
$table = new My_Table();
$view = new My_View();
$model = new My_Model($table, $view);
```

All my models extends a Same class that take care of the construction, message handling and getters for forms to interact with the model.

Now I have to inject a `model` into a `model` and I was looking for a passive static way of doing this. In my model's parent class I have added a static method `inject` which is called in the application bootstrap. I pass two string in the form of `key => value` where the key is the name of the variable that have to be created in the model and the value is the string that represents the class to be instanciated.

```
My_Model::inject('dependentModel', 'My_Other_Model')
```

The issue arise when I try to use the key as a new member variable through the following code :

```
protected function _initDependency()
{
    $this->_table = null;

    foreach (self::$_staticDependency as $key => $dependency) {
        $varName = '_' . $key;
        $this->{$$varName} = new $dependency();
    }
}
```

I get the following message

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _dependentModel
```

What would be the best way to achieve that, knowing that I want to create my models ignorants of their dependencies?

Comment: `$this->{$varName} = new $dependency();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays

```
class Foo {
  private $_data = array();


  protected function _initDependency()
  {
    $this->_table = null;

    foreach (self::$_staticDependency as $key => $dependency) {
      $varName = '_' . $key;
      $this->_data[$varName] = new $dependency();
    }
  }
}
```

(As a side effect this also removes the variable-variables)

You can use `__get()`, `__set()`, `__isset()` and `__unset()` to simulate the property-behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, parts of it will be useful. I had a circular class instanciation problem, so I think I'll go with a `factory/builder` pattern

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to consider any proper ORM like Doctrine2. You save yourself time to reinvent the wheel. Doctrine2 is easy to set up with ZF and there is a lot of information on the net in case you get stuck.